# Can we override CheckTokenEndpoint and provide custom CheckTokenEndpoint in Spring Oauth2?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

My application has separate authorization server and resource server. Authorization server provides access token to resource server. Resource server then sends the request for protected resource with access token.

Resource server uses `RemoteTokenServices` to validate whether the access token is proper or not.

```
@Bean
public RemoteTokenServices remoteTokenServices(final @Value("${auth.server.url}") String checkTokenUrl,
    final @Value("${auth.server.clientId}") String clientId,
    final @Value("${auth.server.clientsecret}") String clientSecret) 
{
  final RemoteTokenServices remoteTokenServices = new RemoteTokenServices();
  remoteTokenServices.setCheckTokenEndpointUrl(checkTokenUrl+"?name=value");
  remoteTokenServices.setClientId(clientId);
  remoteTokenServices.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
  remoteTokenServices.setAccessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter());
  return remoteTokenServices;
}
```

**application.yml**

```
auth:
    server:
      url: http://localhost:9191/api/oauth/check_token/
      clientId: clientid
      clientsecret: secret
```

I want to pass additional parameter like resource id so that I can verify if the token is authorized for that resource or not.

I want to get that parameter in `org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.CheckTokenEndpoint`, 
and want override below method to add some logic. Is it possible?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/oauth/check_token")
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, ?> checkToken(@RequestParam("token") String value) {
  OAuth2AccessToken token = resourceServerTokenServices.readAccessToken(value);
  if (token == null) {
    throw new InvalidTokenException("Token was not recognised");
  }

  if (token.isExpired()) {
    throw new InvalidTokenException("Token has expired");
  }

  OAuth2Authentication authentication = resourceServerTokenServices.loadAuthentication(token.getValue());

  Map<String, ?> response = accessTokenConverter.convertAccessToken(token, authentication);

  return response;
}
```

How to send some parameter to oauth/check_token and override `checkToken()` method?

Basically what I am doing is when access token is generated, I am saving some record about the resources that token is allowed for.

When I receive the request for the resource on resource server, I want to pass the resource id to auth server and want to verify the token is authorized for that resource or not?

Comment: What is the 'resource id' you are talking about? Can you not get it from the token itself?

Answer (score 0):

I've just create new CustomCheckTokenEndpoint and copy whole code of CheckTokenEndpoint  then override checkToken(...) method

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class CustomAuthorizationServer extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.pathMapping("/oauth/check_token", "/my/oauth/check_token");
   }
}
**CustomCheckTokenEndpoint.java**
public class CustomCheckTokenEndpoint {
     // copy whole CheckTokenEndpoint
    @RequestMapping(value = "/my/oauth/check_token")
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<String, ?> checkToken(String value) {
        // your code will be here
    }
}
```